# Internet Explorer 8 displays a black to grey gradient instead of a trasnparent png

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Internet Explorer 8 is doing the weirdest thing: I have a div with text, with a white transparency .png as background. Instead of displaing this, IE8 is showing a black to grey gradient, with one of the corners with a weird radius.

Also, this is happening in my W7 with IE8, but I have tried in a different PC with the same setup and it does not happen.

Any ideas or experiences?

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: the transparent image was a 1x1px image on repeat, which for some reason soemtimes caused that error in IE8. I replaced it for a 10x10 pixels version and now it displays correctly.